# How to add a cell to my Table View dynamically using a button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add a cell to my table view with a button. Everything I have read and watched suggests that what I have written should work, but it doesn't. Any suggestions?

```
import UIKit

class RootViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource,     UITableViewDelegate {
private var cellPointSize: CGFloat!
private var albumsList: AlbumList!
private var albums:[Album]!
private let albumCell = "Album"

@IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let preferredTableViewFont = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
    cellPointSize = preferredTableViewFont.pointSize
    albumsList = AlbumList.sharedAlbumList
    albums = albumsList.albums
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self
    self.myTableView.delegate = self

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return albums.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Albums"
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(albumCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        //cell.textLabel?.font = fontForDisplay(atIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = albums[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = albums[indexPath.row].artist
        return cell
       }

@IBAction func addNewAlbumAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var newAlbum = Album(nameIn: "New Title", yearIn: "New Year", artistIn: "New Artist", labelIn: "New Label")
    albumsList.addAlbum(newAlbum)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
    })
}

func saveData(albumObject: Album) {
    var archiveArray = NSMutableArray(capacity: albums.count)
    for a in albums {
        var albumEncodedObject = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(a)
        archiveArray.addObject(albumEncodedObject)
    }

    var userData = NSUserDefaults()
    userData.setObject(archiveArray, forKey: "albums")
    userData.synchronize()
}
```

My albums array is adding the data correctly. I can see the albums in the debugger. The delegate methods are never being called after the first time when the app loads. Any ideas?

Comment: i think you should use directly `self.myTableView.reloadData()` insted of `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
    })`

Comment: Tried it. Wasn't using the dispatch_async stuff until I saw someone suggest it. I don't think it makes a difference. I'm not doing anything complex at all, so all this stuff should be happening on the main thread anyway. I just changed it back to no dispatch async again and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Sure. How do I do that?

Comment: Ok, thank you. jghas br

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, it returns `albums.count`

but when the button is pressed, you add the new `album` to `albumsList`

The problem is, `albums` will not get update.

---

So I think you should return `albumsList.albums.count` instead.

and in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you modify the cell correspond to `albumsList.albums[indexPath.row]`

Comment: Wow, I actually had that thought earlier, but albums is just a reference to albumsList.albums. So I should be able to use albums[] and albumsList.albums interchangeably right? That was my reasoning anyway. But I made your suggested changes and it works!!! Thank you. But why is my reasoning wrong? Album is a class?!?

Comment: [Album] is not reference type. It's a struct (Swift array is struct). So basically you just copy it, you do not reference it.

Comment: Well that explains everything. Thank you much.